# Проблема с Jquery Autocomplete при заполнении нескольких полей

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete, each

**Проблема с Jquery Autocomplete при заполнении нескольких полей**

Необходимо сделать скрипт автозаполения полей input когда пользователь вводит адрес.

Для этого написал php-скрипт, который используя REST API сервиса Ahunter.ru (http://ahunter.ru/site/doc/api/suggest/address), собирает подсказки для вводимого пользователем адреса, обрабатывает их и формирует массив в формате JSON, для его последующей обработки Jquery Autocomplete

**Проблемы возникли при написании скрипта на Jquery для ajax-запроса к php-скрипту. Код  скрипта на Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('.address').each(function(){

$(this).autocomplete({ source: function(request,response) {
    
 var val =  $('.address').val();

    
    $.getJSON('http://doc.army-help.ru/files/1.php?query=' + val,  function(data){
         
        var suggestions = []; // массив для хранения результатов
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                     
                suggestions.push(val.value); // добавляем все элементы
            });
            response(suggestions);
        });
    
    }     
});


});

</script>
```

Скрипт работает, но проблема заключается в том, что для обработки нескольких полей с  классом address на странице используется функция .each. При этом обрабатываются все поля, но данные для переменной val (в нее помещается введенные пользователем данные) берутся только из 1-го по порядку класса address.

**!!! ВОПРОС:**

Не понимаю как заполнять переменную val содержанием именно того input, который заполняет пользователь. Пробовал варианты -  var val =  $(this).val();  и   var val =  this.value;  но они не работают.

Адрес php-скрипта - http://doc.army-help.ru/files/1.php?query=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Адрес страницы с ajax-скриптом - http://doc.army-help.ru/files/2.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение найдено:**

https://qna.habr.com/q/930571

В данном случае обходить все поля неправильно, each тут не помощник.
Правильно будет отслеживать ввод данных в поле и тут же обрабатывать из него данные:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.address', function(){
 var item = $(this);
item.autocomplete({ source: function(request,response) {
 var val = item.val();
 $.getJSON('http://doc.army-help.ru/files/1.php?query=' + val,  function(data){
        
        var suggestions = []; // массив для хранения результатов
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    
                suggestions.push(val.value); // добавляем все элементы
            });
            response(suggestions);
        });
            
  }     
});
});
```